# When the last part of expression will be returned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following expression taken from jQuery native code:

```
handlers = ( jQuery._data( this, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] || []
```

I'm curios under which conditions the last part of the expression - `[]` - will be assigned to the `handlers` variable? Here is my speculation:

1) This part is executed first `( jQuery._data( this, "events" ) || {} )`. If there are no attached events `jQuery._data( this, "events" ) === undefined`, then the empty object is returned.

2) Then this part `{}[event.type] || []` is processed. If `event.type` is undefined, then an array is returned and assigned to the `handlers` variable. So it means that for the array to be returned it is enough that `event.type` is undefined?

Am I right?

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it means that for the array to be returned it is enough that `event.type` is `undefined`?

Yes, but the array is also returned if `event.type` has a value which does not exist as property name in the object. That is, if the first expression evaluates to to the empty object, *any* value of `event.type` will result in the array being returned.

Example:

```
({}['click'] || [])
```

Comment: So it basically checks that:  
1) jQuery._data( this, "events" ) exists  
2) it has event.type property.  Correct?

Comment: Thanks! Why not check in this way: `jQuery._data( this, "events" ) && jQuery._data( this, "events" )[event.type]` ?

Comment: Because they didn't ;) You can do that of course, but in this case you repeat `jQuery._data( this, "events" )`, which they probably wanted to avoid.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm going to use 'conventional' approach when checking values with short names - obj && obj.property - and this approach when checking values with long names or involved operations - (some_long_name_for_object_2 || {})['property']

Answer (score 2):

That's basically right

it's just trying to do this.

```
jQuery._data(this, "events")[event.type] || []
```

However, if `jQuery._data(this, "events")` is falsey (undefined), they're setting it to a `{}` first so that the `[event.type]` object property accessor doesn't throw a fit.

---

Another way to write this might be

```
handlers = (function(context){
  var events = jQuery._data(context, "events") || {};
  return events[event.type] || [];    
})(this);
```

Comment: Almost: `events && events[event.type] ? events[event.type] : []` is what it should say. Your alternative notation _could_ return `undefined` as it now stands

Comment: I was just fixing that for her. Nice catch, Elias.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I think I made it a little more legible :)

Answer (score 1):

- *"If there are no attached events `jQuery._data( this, "events" ) === undefined`, then the empty object is returned."*

Almost, the logical `||` (OR) will also evaluate the given expression (`jQuery._data(this, 'events') || {})` to an empty object literal if the `_data` call returns null, 0, or false... any falsy value, basically.

- *"So it means that for the array to be returned it is enough that event.type is undefined"*

Yes, be it undefined in the return value of `jQuery._data(this, 'events')` or in the emtpy object literal (in which case it'll almost certainly be undefined), this will evaluate to an empty array, and that's what `handlers` will be assigned.

If you were stark-raving mad, and set a property on the Object prototype, for some reason:

```
Object.prototype.click = 'I was set by a madman';
```

Your code would *never* return an empty array for the `click` event type, because the property `click` will *always* be found, be it on the instance, or further up the prototype chain. That's why you should never touch the native prototypes, save for some rare cases. Even then, just Don't set *non-function* properties on the `Object.prototype`

Comment: Awsome example! I've laughed out loud about the joke with madman :)))